# Chatbox logout message

Tags: php, postgresql

I have a table with four rows (time, name, text and chat_id)

```
             time             |     name      |     text     | chat_id 
------------------------------+---------------+--------------+---------
 2017-03-25 13:15:02.70061+00 | James Douglas | Hello world! |     478
(1 row)
```

here is the insert thingy that inserts to the database (which is working fine):

```
  $db->perform("insert into chat(name,text) values($1,$2)",$_SESSION['name'],$_POST['text']);
```

and here is the thing that shows the data on the page as a chat message:

```
  $('#chatbox').append('<div><p><b>'+v.name+'</b> - <span>'+v.text+'</span><span style="display: inline-block; float: right;"><small>('+v.timee+')</small></span></div>');
```

and the logout message:

```
  $db->perform("insert into chat(name, text) values($1,$2)",$_SESSION['name'],' has left the chat session');
```

all of that is mostly working fine, and the chat messages look like:

**James Douglas** - Hello world! (Saturday 13:15)

Unfortunately, the logout messages look like:

**James Douglas** - has left the chat session (Saturday 13:26)

how would I make the logout messages look like this instead?
*James Douglas has left the chat session*

(Presumably editing these two)

```
 $('#chatbox').append('<div><p><b>'+v.name+'</b> - <span>'+v.text+'</span><span style="display: inline-block; float: right;"><small>('+v.timee+')</small></span></div>');

 $db->perform("insert into chat(name, text) values($1,$2)",$_SESSION['name'],' has left the chat session');
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your approach is wrong. You should separate the text messages from the action messages. Action messages may be all messages `somebody joined/left/changed nickname etc`. You can add one field in your database like:

```
             time             |     name      |     text     | chat_id | type
------------------------------+---------------+--------------+---------+---------
 2017-03-25 13:15:02.70061+00 | James Douglas | Hello world! |     478 | text
------------------------------+---------------+--------------+---------+---------
 2017-03-25 13:15:12.70061+00 | James Douglas |           1  |     479 | action
```

and then have an other table that you associate the action ids with their respective texts like:

```
    id    |    text
----------+-------------------------
    1     |   User left the channel
----------+-------------------------
    2     |   User joined the channel
```

so when you are trying to print the rows you can have different css classes for the different types of text

```
  $('#chatbox').append('<div class="text-type-'+v.type+'"><p><b>'+v.name+'</b> - <span>'+v.text+'</span><span style="display: inline-block; float: right;"><small>('+v.timee+')</small></span></div>');
```

Comment: Thank you so much!